# How to create a session variable if none exists prior, but ignore if variable exists but is blank

Tags: php, session

I have this problem. I want to detect if there is not a session variable and create one, but if one already exists and is empty I want to leave it alone.

Say I have this to create my session variable if none is detected:

```
if (!$_SESSION['second_prefix']){$_SESSION['second_prefix'] = "";}
```

How should I change this to not perform any action is `$_SESSION['second_prefix']` exists but is purposely blank?

Hudson

Comment: Technically, assigning an empty string to something that's already set to an empty string is effectively a no-op...

Comment: @Amber: The question isn't "how can I check whether a variable is an empty string", it's "how can I check whether a variable has been set". Initialising a variable is hardly a no-op.

Comment: @pinkgothic: The OP wants to initialize it if it's not already set. Read the question.

Comment: @Amber: I very much did. You said 'assigning an empty string to something that's already set to an empty string'. The OP has no interest in assigning an empty string to a variable already set with an empty string. Yes, you *can* do that, so `if ($variable)` is a certain degree of fine if strings are really the only type you're using - which I presume you mean - but `if ($variable)` is the same as `if (empty($variable))` (though former will throw an error on uninitialised vars, latter will not), meaning `0` would trigger it, also. Overwriting that with an empty string may be entirely undesired.

Comment: @pinkgothic: true, good point. Given the context provided, however (`'second_prefix'` et cetera), it seems that it was intended to always be a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['second_prefix'])){
  $_SESSION['second_prefix'] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 3):

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will do this for you.

The important thing about `if(isset($blah))` as opposed to `if($blah)` is the isset() will be true even if $blah is empty. In other words, for your case, `$_SESSION['second_prefix']=""`

However, isset() will return false if $blah is NULL. So, while `$blah=""` is fine, `$blah=NULL` would return false for `isset($blah)`.

( [is_null()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) will check if a variable is NULL )